# Running nuxt.js in bitbucket-pipeline throws 'undefined' error

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, bitbucket, nuxt.js, bitbucket-pipelines

Trying to build static pages via [nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/) in [bitbucket-pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines).

However I keep getting funny error on `nuxt generate` step. It throws the `Nuxt Fatal Error` of `undefined`

Here I'm providing `nuxt.config.js`, `bitbucket-pipeline.yml`, `package.json` and screenshot from bitbucket-pipeline.

*nuxt.config.js*

```js
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    { src: '~plugins/i18n.js' }
  ],
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: 'public-web',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'Nuxt.js project' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },
  modules: [
    'nuxt-i18n',
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '~/modules/hooks'
  ],
  // TODO: LEAVE ONLY LANGUAGES REQUIRED PER TENANT
  i18n: {
    locales: [
      {
        code: 'ru',
        iso: 'ru-RU',
        name: 'Russian',
        file: 'ru_RU.json'
      },
      {
        code: 'en',
        iso: 'en-US',
        name: 'English',
        file: 'en.json'
      },
      {
        code: 'de',
        iso: 'de-CH',
        name: 'Dutch',
        file: 'de_CH.json'
      },
      {
        code: 'fr',
        iso: 'fr-CH',
        name: 'French',
        file: 'fr.json'
      },
      {
        code: 'nl-de',
        iso: 'nl-NL',
        name: 'Dutch',
        file: 'nl_NL.json'
      }
    ],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    ueI18nLoader: false,
    // Separator used to generated routes name for each locale, you shouldn't
    // need to change this
    routesNameSeparator: '___',

    // Suffix added to generated routes name for default locale if strategy is prefix_and_default,
    // you shouldn't need to change this
    defaultLocaleRouteNameSuffix: 'default',

    // Routes generation strategy, can be set to one of the following:
    // - 'no_prefix': routes won't be prefixed
    // - 'prefix_except_default': add locale prefix for every locale except default
    // - 'prefix': add locale prefix for every locale
    // - 'prefix_and_default': add locale prefix for every locale and default
    strategy: 'prefix',
    // Wether or not the translations should be lazy-loaded, if this is enabled,
    // you MUST configure langDir option, and locales must be an array of objects,
    // each containing a file key
    lazy: true,

    // Directory that contains translations files when lazy-loading messages,
    // this CAN NOT be empty if lazy-loading is enabled
    // langDir: null,
    langDir: 'locales/',
    // Set this to a path to which you want to redirect users accessing root URL (/)
    // rootRedirect: 'index.html',

    // Enable browser language detection to automatically redirect user
    // to their preferred language as they visit your app for the first time
    // Set to false to disable
    detectBrowserLanguage: {
      // If enabled, a cookie is set once a user has been redirected to his
      // preferred language to prevent subsequent redirections
      // Set to false to redirect every time
      useCookie: true,
      // Cookie name
      cookieKey: 'i18n_redirected',
      // Set to always redirect to value stored in the cookie, not just once
      alwaysRedirect: false,
      // If no locale for the browsers locale is a match, use this one as a fallback
      fallbackLocale: 'en'
    },
    // TODO: Uncomment for dev
    // detectBrowserLanguage: false,
    // If true, SEO metadata is generated for routes that have i18n enabled.
    // Note that performance can suffer with this enabled and there might be compatibility
    // issues with some plugins. Recommended way is to set up SEO as described in:
    // https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/seo.html#improving-performance
    // TODO: Enable on prod
    seo: false,
    // Fallback base URL to use as prefix for alternate URLs in hreflang tags.
    // By default VueRouter's base URL will be used and only if that is not available,
    // fallback URL will be used.
    // TODO: Replace by prod domain
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    vueI18n: {
      fallbackLocale: 'en'
    },
    // Called right before app's locale changes
    // beforeLanguageSwitch: (oldLocale, newLocale) => null,

    // // Called after app's locale has changed
    // onLanguageSwitched: (oldLocale, newLocale) => null
  },
  axios: {},
  css: [
    '@/assets/styles/main.scss'
  ],
  /*
  ** Customize the progress bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#3B8070' },
  loaders: {
    // file: {},
    // fontUrl: { limit: 1000 },
    imgUrl: {
      limit: 1000,
      fallback: require.resolve('responsive-loader'),
      quality: 85
    },
    // pugPlain: {},
    // vue: {
    //   transformAssetUrls: {
    //     video: 'src',
    //     source: 'src',
    //     object: 'src',
    //     embed: 'src'
    //   }
    // },
    // css: {},
    // cssModules: {
    //   localIdentName: '[local]_[hash:base64:5]'
    // },
    // sass: {
    //   indentedSyntax: true
    // },
    // scss: {},
    // stylus: {},
    // vueStyle: {}
  },
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** Run ESLint on save
    */
    extend (config, { isDev, isClient, loaders }) {
      if (isDev && isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        })
      }
    }
  }
};
```

*bitbucket-pipeline.yml*

```
    pipelines:
      branches:
      master:
        - step:
            name: Build and Test Static Pages
            deployment: public-web
            image: node:current
            cache:
              - node
            script:
              - npm install
              - npm run precommit
              - npm run generate
```

*package.json*

```js
{
  "name": "public-web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Nuxt.js project",
  "author": "test@dev.com",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "precommit": "npm run lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.8.0",
    "nuxt": "2.10",
    "nuxt-i18n": "^6.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@lokalise/node-api": "^1.4.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "prettier": "1.19.1",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "responsive-loader": "^1.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "unzipper": "^0.10.5"
  }
}
```

[image: Output of npm run generate command]

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` as well please?

Comment: Sure. Updated the description by adding `package.json`

Comment: I can't seem to be able to reproduce on a fresh nuxt.js bitbucket repository. Can you share your nuxt.config.js as well? Might have to do with your config or your project.

Comment: Here you go. Updated description again - Added `nuxt.config.js` file

Comment: Hard to tell, but Nuxt.js default install with i18n plugin builds without problems on Bitbucket. Can you build without issues locally? I see you have a custom `modules/hooks`, maybe something is preventing the build in there?

Comment: Yeah, I am able to build/generate pages locally without errors. 
But you thanks for giving a hint on `modulues/hooks`. Let me do the investigation on that direction then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appeared to be in one of the `npm` modules. To be precise the problem was in `@lokalise/node-api`.
This package would throw not useful error when invalid creds were provided.

In case if somebody faces the same problems I hope this would help